# run text file throught java using unix

Tags: java, unix

i want it to compile my java program given a text file without having to hard code the file name into my program. I just don't know how the command line for it.

for example:

```
javac Main1.java

java Main1 myText.txt
```

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main` methods' `args` parameter is there for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // `args` contains command line arguments.
    String filename = args[0];
    ...
}
```

See [Command line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).